# FFMPEG Thumbnail Generation in certain timespan

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I'm generating thumbnails in regular intervals based on the length of a video:

```
ffmpeg -i "/my/dir/tmp/mymovie.mp4" -vf fps=4/259 /my/dir/tmp/123456/mymoviethumb%d.jpg
```

Now I want to use just the first 30 seconds of the video and grab 5 thumbnails out of them. I'm stuck, can anybody help me out and give me an example command how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -t 30 -vf fps=1/6:round=inf out_%d.jpg`

where:

`-t 30` - limit duration to 30s

`fps=1/6` - 30s / 5 = 6s, round away from 0